# filtering out lowest numbers in a column by group

Tags: r, filter

I have the following dataset:

```
head(tot_docks, n = 10)
       id tot
1      72  39
2771   79  33
5541   82  27
8310   83  62
8900   83   3
11079 116  39
13848 119  19
14584 119   8
14662 119   0
15922 119   2
```

I need to keep the ids with the highest values. There are sometimes several duplicates in `id` , and I only want to keep the one that is has the highest value in `tot`.   For example, if we look at `id` 119, I only need like to keep the row where 119 is 39 as that is the highest value.  Is there a quick formula to do this in R ?

```
dput(tot_docks)
structure(list(id = c(72L, 79L, 82L, 83L, 83L, 116L, 119L, 119L, 
119L, 119L, 119L, 119L, 119L, 120L, 127L, 128L, 128L, 137L, 143L, 
144L, 146L, 147L, 150L, 151L, 152L, 153L, 153L, 153L, 153L, 157L, 
157L, 160L, 161L, 164L, 167L, 168L, 173L, 173L, 173L, 174L, 195L, 
195L, 212L, 216L, 217L, 217L, 217L, 217L, 218L, 223L, 224L, 225L, 
228L, 229L, 232L, 233L, 236L, 236L, 236L, 236L, 236L, 237L, 237L, 
238L, 239L, 241L, 242L, 243L, 243L, 243L, 243L, 243L, 243L, 243L, 
243L, 243L, 243L, 243L, 244L, 245L, 247L, 248L, 249L, 250L, 251L, 
252L, 253L, 253L, 253L, 253L, 253L, 253L, 253L, 253L, 253L, 253L, 
253L, 253L, 253L, 253L, 253L, 253L, 253L, 253L, 253L, 253L, 253L, 
253L, 253L, 253L, 253L, 254L, 254L, 254L, 257L, 258L, 259L, 259L, 
260L, 260L, 261L, 262L, 263L, 264L, 265L, 266L, 266L, 267L, 268L, 
270L, 274L, 275L, 276L, 278L, 279L, 279L, 279L, 279L, 279L, 279L, 
279L, 279L, 279L, 279L, 279L, 279L, 279L, 279L, 279L, 279L, 280L, 
281L, 282L, 284L, 285L, 289L, 290L, 291L, 293L, 294L, 295L, 296L, 
297L, 298L, 300L, 301L, 302L, 303L, 304L, 305L, 305L, 306L, 307L, 
308L, 309L, 310L, 311L, 312L, 313L, 314L, 315L, 315L, 316L, 317L, 
318L, 318L, 318L, 319L, 320L, 321L, 321L, 322L, 323L, 324L, 325L, 
325L, 325L, 325L, 325L, 325L, 326L, 327L, 328L, 329L, 330L, 330L, 
331L, 332L, 334L, 335L, 336L, 337L, 339L, 340L, 341L, 342L, 343L, 
344L, 345L, 346L, 347L, 347L, 347L, 347L, 348L, 348L, 349L, 350L, 
351L, 351L, 351L, 351L, 351L, 352L, 353L, 354L, 355L, 356L, 357L, 
357L, 357L, 357L, 357L, 358L, 359L, 360L, 361L, 362L, 363L, 364L, 
365L, 366L, 367L, 368L, 369L, 372L, 373L, 375L, 376L, 376L, 376L, 
376L, 376L, 376L, 376L, 376L, 376L, 376L, 376L, 376L, 376L, 376L, 
376L, 376L, 376L, 376L, 376L, 377L, 379L, 380L, 382L, 383L, 384L, 
384L, 385L, 386L, 387L, 388L, 389L, 390L, 391L, 392L, 392L, 392L, 
392L, 392L, 392L, 393L, 394L, 394L, 395L, 396L, 397L, 398L, 399L, 
400L, 401L, 402L, 403L, 403L, 405L, 405L, 406L, 407L, 407L, 407L, 
408L, 409L, 410L, 411L, 412L, 414L, 415L, 416L, 417L, 417L, 418L, 
419L, 419L, 420L, 421L, 422L, 422L, 423L, 426L, 427L, 428L, 430L, 
432L, 432L, 433L, 433L, 434L, 435L, 436L, 437L, 438L, 439L, 440L, 
440L, 441L, 442L, 443L, 444L, 444L, 445L, 446L, 447L, 448L, 449L, 
450L, 453L, 454L, 455L, 455L, 455L, 455L, 455L, 456L, 457L, 458L, 
459L, 459L, 460L, 461L, 462L, 463L, 465L, 466L, 467L, 468L, 469L, 
470L, 471L, 472L, 473L, 473L, 473L, 473L, 473L, 473L, 473L, 473L, 
473L, 473L, 473L, 473L, 473L, 473L, 473L, 473L, 473L, 474L, 474L, 
475L, 476L, 477L, 478L, 479L, 480L, 481L, 482L, 483L, 484L, 485L, 
486L, 487L, 488L, 489L, 490L, 490L, 490L, 490L, 490L, 491L, 492L, 
492L, 493L, 494L, 495L, 496L, 497L, 497L, 497L, 498L, 499L, 500L, 
501L, 502L, 502L, 503L, 504L, 504L, 505L, 507L, 507L, 507L, 508L, 
509L, 510L, 510L, 511L, 512L, 513L, 514L, 515L, 516L, 516L, 517L, 
517L, 517L, 517L, 518L, 519L, 519L, 519L, 519L, 520L, 521L, 522L, 
523L, 524L, 525L, 526L, 527L, 528L, 529L, 530L, 531L, 532L, 533L, 
534L, 534L, 534L, 534L, 536L, 537L, 537L, 538L, 538L, 539L, 540L, 
545L, 546L, 546L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 
2006L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2012L, 2017L, 2021L, 2022L, 2023L, 
3002L, 3041L, 3042L, 3043L, 3044L, 3046L, 3046L, 3047L, 3048L, 
3049L, 3050L, 3051L, 3052L, 3053L, 3054L, 3055L, 3056L, 3057L, 
3058L, 3059L, 3060L, 3061L, 3061L, 3061L, 3062L, 3063L, 3063L, 
3064L, 3065L, 3066L, 3067L, 3068L, 3069L, 3069L, 3069L, 3070L, 
3071L, 3072L, 3073L, 3074L, 3075L, 3076L, 3077L, 3077L, 3078L, 
3079L, 3080L, 3081L, 3082L, 3083L, 3084L, 3085L, 3086L, 3086L, 
3086L, 3087L, 3087L, 3088L, 3089L, 3090L, 3090L, 3091L, 3092L, 
3093L), tot = c(39L, 33L, 27L, 62L, 3L, 39L, 19L, 8L, 0L, 2L, 
1L, 3L, 4L, 19L, 31L, 30L, 29L, 46L, 24L, 19L, 39L, 33L, 31L, 
33L, 29L, 43L, 35L, 31L, 3L, 23L, 0L, 26L, 35L, 47L, 45L, 47L, 
51L, 47L, 31L, 30L, 25L, 45L, 28L, 23L, 39L, 0L, 2L, 3L, 39L, 
33L, 31L, 37L, 55L, 23L, 23L, 38L, 39L, 0L, 12L, 6L, 5L, 39L, 
0L, 31L, 31L, 23L, 23L, 31L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 9L, 10L, 
11L, 13L, 31L, 23L, 20L, 23L, 27L, 40L, 27L, 33L, 55L, 1L, 7L, 
8L, 10L, 11L, 13L, 20L, 24L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 
35L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 41L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 31L, 7L, 3L, 39L, 
23L, 39L, 31L, 35L, 27L, 27L, 24L, 31L, 27L, 35L, 24L, 0L, 57L, 
27L, 23L, 31L, 19L, 25L, 19L, 36L, 0L, 9L, 12L, 13L, 15L, 16L, 
17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 31L, 59L, 27L, 43L, 
47L, 19L, 29L, 20L, 55L, 3L, 24L, 35L, 27L, 35L, 55L, 37L, 23L, 
31L, 36L, 32L, 33L, 37L, 29L, 27L, 41L, 36L, 31L, 31L, 23L, 39L, 
29L, 17L, 43L, 27L, 31L, 2L, 0L, 33L, 39L, 27L, 26L, 31L, 39L, 
51L, 35L, 31L, 27L, 25L, 5L, 36L, 27L, 39L, 23L, 31L, 39L, 0L, 
27L, 24L, 31L, 27L, 36L, 37L, 24L, 27L, 19L, 29L, 23L, 23L, 35L, 
27L, 35L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 42L, 41L, 3L, 28L, 39L, 35L, 34L, 21L, 
19L, 36L, 27L, 23L, 43L, 23L, 27L, 11L, 10L, 6L, 3L, 36L, 55L, 
39L, 43L, 57L, 49L, 27L, 31L, 33L, 34L, 39L, 35L, 27L, 19L, 30L, 
43L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 9L, 12L, 16L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 23L, 24L, 26L, 
27L, 28L, 29L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 47L, 42L, 39L, 36L, 39L, 31L, 0L, 
29L, 43L, 39L, 35L, 27L, 31L, 31L, 32L, 31L, 13L, 26L, 0L, 1L, 
31L, 32L, 4L, 30L, 25L, 27L, 31L, 27L, 15L, 42L, 42L, 31L, 0L, 
40L, 39L, 34L, 3L, 13L, 37L, 23L, 19L, 35L, 23L, 29L, 24L, 42L, 
31L, 23L, 22L, 23L, 23L, 16L, 23L, 19L, 55L, 54L, 39L, 31L, 47L, 
31L, 27L, 31L, 27L, 39L, 38L, 27L, 47L, 27L, 24L, 27L, 39L, 32L, 
28L, 35L, 51L, 23L, 52L, 51L, 42L, 39L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 59L, 39L, 
35L, 3L, 23L, 32L, 36L, 39L, 35L, 39L, 31L, 49L, 50L, 23L, 39L, 
47L, 25L, 39L, 35L, 34L, 59L, 57L, 37L, 31L, 41L, 42L, 0L, 2L, 
4L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 12L, 13L, 15L, 16L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 
32L, 47L, 3L, 37L, 47L, 59L, 31L, 31L, 27L, 25L, 39L, 35L, 44L, 
39L, 39L, 36L, 41L, 37L, 59L, 0L, 20L, 58L, 55L, 53L, 49L, 48L, 
34L, 35L, 25L, 47L, 59L, 57L, 0L, 30L, 36L, 52L, 43L, 30L, 0L, 
29L, 45L, 1L, 36L, 47L, 0L, 29L, 24L, 36L, 51L, 1L, 33L, 27L, 
27L, 53L, 35L, 19L, 31L, 59L, 55L, 53L, 0L, 39L, 61L, 62L, 25L, 
47L, 39L, 39L, 51L, 51L, 57L, 39L, 39L, 59L, 39L, 41L, 36L, 39L, 
43L, 50L, 31L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 29L, 39L, 40L, 3L, 39L, 31L, 30L, 
27L, 38L, 1L, 30L, 15L, 27L, 39L, 36L, 12L, 42L, 49L, 24L, 35L, 
39L, 36L, 39L, 43L, 33L, 36L, 25L, 24L, 19L, 19L, 27L, 19L, 13L, 
21L, 19L, 18L, 21L, 0L, 23L, 23L, 19L, 23L, 23L, 18L, 24L, 19L, 
19L, 21L, 2L, 0L, 23L, 20L, 0L, 23L, 27L, 19L, 27L, 24L, 25L, 
4L, 24L, 23L, 19L, 24L, 27L, 31L, 33L, 24L, 23L, 33L, 0L, 24L, 
21L, 23L, 25L, 30L, 19L, 25L, 25L, 0L, 23L, 36L, 0L, 22L, 0L, 
31L, 0L, 31L, 27L, 28L)), .Names = c("id", "tot"), row.names = c(1L, 
2771L, 5541L, 8310L, 8900L, 11079L, 13848L, 14584L, 14662L, 15922L, 
15927L, 15930L, 15932L, 16617L, 19386L, 22155L, 23595L, 24924L, 
27693L, 30462L, 33231L, 36000L, 38769L, 41538L, 44307L, 47076L, 
49118L, 49137L, 49240L, 49845L, 51090L, 52614L, 55383L, 58152L, 
60921L, 63690L, 66459L, 67442L, 67993L, 69228L, 71997L, 72489L, 
74766L, 77535L, 80304L, 82888L, 82892L, 82944L, 83073L, 85842L, 
88611L, 91380L, 94149L, 96918L, 99687L, 102456L, 105225L, 105469L, 
105494L, 105518L, 106008L, 107994L, 108449L, 110763L, 113532L, 
116301L, 119070L, 121839L, 123709L, 123712L, 123713L, 123714L, 
123716L, 123718L, 123719L, 123720L, 123721L, 123723L, 124608L, 
127377L, 130146L, 132915L, 135684L, 138453L, 141222L, 143991L, 
146760L, 148737L, 148738L, 148739L, 148740L, 148741L, 148742L, 
148743L, 148744L, 148745L, 148746L, 148747L, 148748L, 148750L, 
148751L, 148755L, 148756L, 148758L, 148764L, 148766L, 148767L, 
148769L, 148770L, 148771L, 148777L, 149529L, 150081L, 150523L, 
152298L, 155067L, 157836L, 158393L, 160605L, 160870L, 163374L, 
166143L, 168912L, 171681L, 174450L, 177219L, 178808L, 179988L, 
182757L, 185526L, 188295L, 191064L, 193833L, 196602L, 199371L, 
201344L, 201345L, 201346L, 201347L, 201348L, 201350L, 201351L, 
201352L, 201353L, 201354L, 201355L, 201357L, 201362L, 201363L, 
201364L, 202140L, 204909L, 207678L, 210447L, 213216L, 215985L, 
218754L, 221523L, 224292L, 227061L, 229830L, 232599L, 235368L, 
238137L, 240906L, 243675L, 246444L, 249213L, 251982L, 254751L, 
254889L, 257520L, 260289L, 263058L, 265827L, 268596L, 271365L, 
274134L, 276903L, 279672L, 282441L, 282723L, 285210L, 287979L, 
290748L, 292142L, 292162L, 293517L, 296286L, 299055L, 299778L, 
301824L, 304593L, 307362L, 310131L, 310666L, 310683L, 311114L, 
311125L, 312724L, 312900L, 315669L, 318438L, 321207L, 323976L, 
324571L, 326745L, 329514L, 332283L, 335052L, 337821L, 340590L, 
343359L, 346128L, 348897L, 351666L, 354435L, 357204L, 359973L, 
362742L, 365511L, 366294L, 366840L, 368091L, 368280L, 368329L, 
371049L, 373818L, 376587L, 376882L, 376953L, 376954L, 376955L, 
379356L, 382125L, 384894L, 387663L, 390432L, 393201L, 393736L, 
393758L, 393759L, 393760L, 395970L, 398739L, 401508L, 404277L, 
407046L, 409815L, 412584L, 415353L, 418122L, 420891L, 423660L, 
426429L, 429198L, 431967L, 434736L, 437505L, 437967L, 437968L, 
437969L, 437971L, 437974L, 437975L, 437976L, 437977L, 437978L, 
437979L, 437981L, 437982L, 437983L, 437986L, 437987L, 437989L, 
437990L, 437995L, 440274L, 443043L, 445812L, 448581L, 451350L, 
454119L, 456492L, 456888L, 459657L, 462426L, 465195L, 467964L, 
470733L, 473502L, 476271L, 476569L, 478690L, 478752L, 478754L, 
478761L, 479040L, 481809L, 484402L, 484578L, 487347L, 490116L, 
492885L, 495654L, 498423L, 501192L, 503961L, 506730L, 507049L, 
509499L, 511457L, 512268L, 515037L, 516020L, 516104L, 517806L, 
520575L, 523344L, 526113L, 528882L, 531651L, 534420L, 537189L, 
539958L, 542151L, 542727L, 545496L, 546211L, 548265L, 551034L, 
553803L, 555911L, 556572L, 559340L, 562108L, 564876L, 567644L, 
570412L, 572885L, 573180L, 573244L, 575948L, 578716L, 581484L, 
584252L, 587020L, 589788L, 592556L, 593090L, 595324L, 598092L, 
600860L, 603628L, 605895L, 606396L, 609164L, 611932L, 614700L, 
617468L, 620236L, 623004L, 625772L, 628540L, 629075L, 629097L, 
629098L, 629099L, 631308L, 634076L, 636844L, 639612L, 641803L, 
642380L, 645148L, 647916L, 650684L, 653452L, 656220L, 658988L, 
661756L, 664524L, 667292L, 670060L, 672828L, 675596L, 677254L, 
677356L, 677357L, 677359L, 677360L, 677361L, 677363L, 677366L, 
677368L, 677370L, 677377L, 677379L, 677380L, 677382L, 677384L, 
677388L, 678364L, 679071L, 681132L, 683900L, 686668L, 689436L, 
692204L, 694972L, 697740L, 700508L, 703276L, 706044L, 708812L, 
711580L, 714348L, 717116L, 719884L, 722652L, 723762L, 723763L, 
723764L, 723765L, 725420L, 728188L, 730486L, 730956L, 733724L, 
736492L, 739260L, 742028L, 743160L, 743168L, 744796L, 747564L, 
750332L, 753100L, 755868L, 757169L, 758636L, 761404L, 763351L, 
764172L, 766940L, 767412L, 767413L, 769708L, 772476L, 775244L, 
776780L, 778012L, 780780L, 783548L, 786316L, 789084L, 791852L, 
792404L, 794620L, 796475L, 796567L, 796568L, 797388L, 800156L, 
801270L, 802011L, 802197L, 802924L, 805692L, 808460L, 811228L, 
813996L, 816764L, 819532L, 822300L, 825068L, 827836L, 830604L, 
833372L, 836140L, 838908L, 841676L, 841944L, 841945L, 841951L, 
844444L, 847212L, 849183L, 849980L, 850708L, 850726L, 853494L, 
856262L, 859030L, 859697L, 861798L, 864566L, 867334L, 870102L, 
872870L, 875638L, 878406L, 878460L, 881174L, 883942L, 886710L, 
889478L, 892246L, 895014L, 897782L, 900550L, 903318L, 906086L, 
908854L, 911622L, 914390L, 917158L, 919570L, 919926L, 922694L, 
925462L, 928230L, 930998L, 933766L, 936534L, 939302L, 942069L, 
944837L, 947605L, 950373L, 953141L, 955909L, 958677L, 961260L, 
961261L, 961444L, 964212L, 966218L, 966980L, 969748L, 972516L, 
975284L, 978052L, 980820L, 983560L, 983561L, 983588L, 986356L, 
989124L, 991892L, 994660L, 997428L, 1000196L, 1002964L, 1002994L, 
1005732L, 1008500L, 1011268L, 1014036L, 1016804L, 1019572L, 1022340L, 
1025108L, 1027876L, 1028021L, 1028286L, 1030644L, 1032321L, 1033412L, 
1036180L, 1038948L, 1041591L, 1041716L, 1044484L, 1047252L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(tot_docks)`), grouped by 'id', get the index of the max value of 'tot' and subset the dataset (`.SD`)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(tot_docks)[, .SD[which.max(tot)], id]
```

---

Or using `top_n` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
tot_docks %>% 
         group_by(id) %>% 
         top_n(1)
#      id   tot
#   (int) (int)
#1     72    39
#2     79    33
#3     82    27
#4     83    62
#5    116    39
#6    119    19
#7    120    19
#8    127    31
#9    128    30
#10   137    46
#..   ...   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dplyr` arrange to do this:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% arrange(id, desc(tot)) %>% group_by(id) %>% slice(1)
```

For your data, you will get output as follows:

```
Source: local data frame [380 x 2]
Groups: id [380]

      id   tot
   (int) (int)
1     72    39
2     79    33
3     82    27
4     83    62
5    116    39
6    119    19
7    120    19
8    127    31
9    128    30
10   137    46
```